# ldconfig - LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not a known library type

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Since a couple of days ago I'm getting this error below whenever I install any package with shared libraries:

```
"/sbin/ldconfig: $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not a known library type"
```

Why I'm getting this error ?
How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like something got messed up with ldconfig, try

```
sudo /sbin/ldconfig -v
```

Comment: Running into the same issue, could you elaborate the answer a little bit?

Comment: Yeah, why is this an answer?

Answer (score 5):

Most likely the format in one of the files in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` is messed up. These files just contain paths or comments (lines starting with `#`) -- anything else will lead to problems similar to the one you are experiencing.